# Python3 run os.popen with argument?

Tags: subprocess, popen, python-3.4

I am facing difficulties to run below query. Can some one help me to what is the issue on it ?

```
def test():
cmd="python /home/shanaka/volapp/volatility-2.3.1/vol.py -f /home/shanaka/memory_sample/ubuntu-12.04-amd64-jynxkit.mem ---profile={0} {1}".format(OSselection.get(),option.get())
f1 = os.popen3(cmd)
for lt in f1.readlines():
    print(lt)
```

This is not printing, Option.get is taking as another command, an error as below:

```
Volatility Foundation Volatility Framework 2.3.1
```

ERROR   : **main**            : You must specify something to do (try -h)
/bin/sh: 2: linux_banner: not found

Please help me to resolve this.

Comment: it is not your actual code; there is no `os.popen3` in Python 3.4. There are other issues. 1. Make sure you can run `vol.py` manually from the command-line 2. Use `subprocess` module to run it (pass arguments as a list)

Comment: I have used subprocess, Which is giving so many errors, Thats why i used this, without variable this code is working. When i put the variable , not working.

Comment: include the code without variables that "works".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
f1 = os.popen("python /home/shanaka/volapp/volatility-2.3.1/vol.py -f /home/shanaka/memory_sample/ubuntu-12.04-amd64-jynxkit.mem --profile="+OSselection.get().rstrip()+" "+ option.get().rstrip())
```

argument taking as new line, so i have remove the new line.